# Information lost in Huffman Encoding

Tags: javascript, huffman-code

I'm using [this JS-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/huffman-url-compressor) for Huffman-Encoding. It fails on certain strings, as shown in the following example ([RunKit](https://runkit.com/euporos/60872b4df69de0001adb5382)):

```
train = "[1300 [[57 4.56 0.12 11 10260 240] [8.600000000000001 5.2 0.44 44 16447 142] [8.600000000000001 240.8 0.08 12 930] [8.600000000000001 0.16 4.63 230 1080] [8.600000000000001 482.1 2.82 490 572] [8.600000000000001 135.1 28.67 820 1185]]]"

troublesomeInput = "[1300 [[56 4.56 0.12 11 10260 240] [44 5.2 0.44 44 16447 142] [0 240.8 0.08 12 930] [0 0.16 4.63 230 1080] [0 482.1 2.82 490 572] [0 135.1 28.67 820 1185]]]"

let Encoder = huffmanUrlCompressor.createEncoder(train);

let encodedParam = huffmanUrlCompressor.encodeConfig(troublesomeInput,Encoder)

let decodParam= huffmanUrlCompressor.decodeConfig(encodedParam,Encoder)
```

`decodParam` turns out as:

```
[1300 [[56 4.56 0.12 11 10260 240] [44 5.2 0.44 44 16447 142] [0 240.8 0.08 12 930] [0 0.16 4.63 230 1080] [0 482.1 2.82 490 572] [0 135.1 28.67 820 1185]]
```

As you can see, the trailing Bracket has been lost in the process. Am I doing something wrong here or missing the point of what the Huffman-Algorithm is supposed to do? Or should I report this as an issue with the library?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the library to me.

Comment: This likely is the case but since I'm not very knowledgeable about this Alogrithm, I wanted to first rule out any errors on my side.

Comment: Any encoding/decoding algorithm should always produce the original text as output. Unless you've modified `Encoder` or `encodedParam`, that should happen here.

Comment: Well… I have found this implementation to be full of suprises in other regards as well… if e.g. the training string doesn't contain certain characters used in subsequent inputs it will intersperse the output with "undefined" and other stuff… so I thought maybe the training string might have to satisfy  other constraints besides that (the Readme is very sparse). I have a workaround for my purposes but I will take it up with the Lib's maintainer.

Comment: The training string has to have every character that might be in the strings to be encoded, since Huffman coding requires knowing the frequency of each character.

Comment: It would be better if it had a default for characters that aren't in the training string, but this implementation apparently doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For now, this most likely indicates a bug with the library I'm using. I have now opened an [issue on the library's GitHub page](https://github.com/mlacosta/huffman-url-compressor/issues/1). I will update this answer once I get more information, but will consider it closed for now.